# apt-get update ignoring some URLs

Tags: raspbian, apt

Any ideas on why `apt-get update` may be ignoring some URLs? Specifically some translation-related ones.

Sample output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages                  
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages      
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages                              
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages                                   
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/staging armhf Packages                                   
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en_GB                            
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en                 
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_GB          
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en             
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en_GB               
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en                  
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB                  
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/staging Translation-en_GB                                                                           
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/staging Translation-en                                                                              
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en_GB                                                                                
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en                                                                                   
Reading package lists... Done
```

Extra info:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:    8.0
Codename:   jessie

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Comment: The translation files could have been unmodified since last retrieval

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/454867/how-do-ign-and-hit-affect-apt-get-update

Answer (score 1):

They're ignored because they're not present, but it doesn't matter — the original (English) descriptions are in the various `Packages` files (*e.g.* [for `jessie/main`](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages)).